# runST with Hindley-Milner type system

Tags: haskell, monads, hindley-milner

If I understand the ST monad in Haskell correctly, `runST` uses rank-2 types in a clever way to ensure that a computation does not reference any other thread when escaping the monad.

I have a toy language with a Hindley-Milner type system, and my question is the following: is it possible to extend the HM type system with an ad-hoc rule for typing `runST` applications so that the ST monad is safely escapable, **without introducing rank-2 types?**

More precisely, `runST` would have type `forall s a. ST s a -> a` (i.e. rank-1) and the typing rule would first try to generalize the computation type in the same way HM generalizes types in let-expressions, but raise a type error if the `s` type variable is found to be bound.

The above only restricts accepted programs compared to vanilla HM, so it seems sound, but I am unsure. Would this work?

Comment: Yes, you can add `runST` as a special typing rule which does the needed checks.

Comment: Actually the answer is described in the original paper https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=178246

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case the comments to the question are not entirely clear, the judgement you would need is

[image: {\Gamma \vdash e \colon \forall s.\, {\tt ST}\, s\, a ~~~~ s \not\in \text{free}(a)\over \Gamma \vdash {\tt runST}\, e \colon a} ~~\text{[runST]}]

This is of course in conjunction with the other usual typing judgments that come with [Hindley-Milner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system). Interestingly enough, we don't end up needing to make special rules for anything *introducing* an `ST` type, since none of these require type signatures of rank 2:

```
newSTRef :: a -> ST s (STRef s a)
readSTRef :: STRef s a -> ST s a
writeSTRef :: STRef s a -> a -> ST s () 
...
```